# copy specific columns from rows with duplicate data

Tags: vba, excel

Trying to do this all in Excel, as the end-user will not have MS Access (which would make this a billion times easier...).

I have a sheet with rows of data like:

```
ticket  date      name           comments
52      1/1/2016  Edgar          did thing A
52      1/1/2016  Edgar          did thing B
52      1/2/2016  Edgar          did thing C
60      1/5/2016  Steph          looked at X
60      1/5/2016  Steph          looked at Y
```

I need to write a formula (or VBA macro) that will loop through all rows and concatenate comments based on ticket #. i.e. in the above example the end result would be:

```
Ticket   date      name         comments
52       1/1/2016  Edgar        did thing A, did thing B, did thing C
60       1/5/2016  Steph        looked at X, looked at Y
```

I've tried looking through some similar questions, but haven't found anything that i've been able to manipulate to suit my needs.

Would love to hear what you experts think. The sheet will be reconciled monthly, and will be of varying length.

Comment: Assuming the date in line 3 is a typo, and really should be 1/1/2016, I would define a Class with the Comment property being a collection.  A collection of those objects could then be used to generate your final report.

Comment: I'm sorry, I wish I knew what those words meant or how to do that. I'm not sure what you mean by "define a Class"... I'm not a newbie to excel, but that isn't in my grasp as of yet.

Comment: Well, there are other ways to do this; if you are going to do this repeatedly, VBA is the way to go.  As this is not a free code-writing service, I would suggest you devise an approach and try to code it, then post your code here with specific questions where you run into problems.  With regard to classes, Chip Pearson has some excellent material on his [Introduction to Classes](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/Classes.aspx) page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
Sub Main()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1") ' Change the name of your Sheet

    Lastrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row


With ws

    j = 2 ' Start the loop at row 2

    Do While Not IsEmpty(.Cells(j, 1))
            For i = Lastrow To 2 Step -1

                        If j <> i And .Cells(j, 1) = .Cells(i, 1) Then
                            .Cells(j, 4) = .Cells(j, 4) & "," & .Cells(i, 4)
                            .Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
                        End If

            Next i
    j = j + 1
    Loop

End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Great question! This is particularly interesting because you need to adjust your source data in the **opposite** direction of the usual move -- you're getting data into an "un-pivotable" state.

[I wrote about a tutorial for a very similar situation here](http://danwagner.co/combining-data-and-transposing-the-results-to-rows-not-columns-with-vba/) -- instead of putting campers in cabins, though, you need to put comments in tickets. (You also need to combine comments into a single, comma-delimited cell.)

Suppose you were to follow that guide and assemble two `Scripting.Dictionary` objects, `dicTickets` and `dicComments`, where `dicTickets` contains Keys and Items that both represent the "Ticket" values and `dicComments` contains "Comment"s as Keys and "Ticket"s as Items.

With those structures in place, you could loop through them like I do in the **heavily-commented-but-not-tested code below**:

```
'We'll need these, so you'll probably want to declare them up at the top
Dim dicTickets As Scripting.Dictionary, dicComments As Scripting.Dictionary
Set dicTickets = New Scripting.Dictionary
Set dicComments = New Scripting.Dictionary
Dim colCombinedComments As Collection
Dim varTicket As Variant, varComment As Variant
Dim strComments As String
Dim lngIdx As Long

'...
'Fill up the Scripting.Dictionary objects as described in the guide
'...

'"Outer" loop iterates through all the tickets
For Each varTicket in dicTickets.Keys

    '"Inner" loop iterates through all the comments
    For Each varComment in dicComments.Keys

        'Initialize a collection to store all the comments
        Set colCombinedComments = New Collection

        'If this comment matches the current ticket, add it to a string
        If dicComment(varComment) = dicTickets(varTicket) Then
            colCombinedComments.Add dicComment(varComment)
        End If

        'colCombinedComments now contains the comments, yay!

        'Initialize a string to join all the comments together
        'with commas
        strComments = ""

        'Loop through the colCombinedComments, appending each time
        For lngIdx = 1 To colCombinedComments.Count

            'The first time, just make strComments the first comment
            If strComments = "" Then
                strComments = colCombinedComments(lngIdx)

            'Each time after the first time, append with a comma and space
            Else
                strComments = strComments & ", " & colCombinedComments
            End If
        Next lngIdx

        '...
        'Now you can do what you need to with strComments
        '...

    Next varComment

Next varTicket
```

Comment: Thanks so much Dan! This is beefy and a bit over my head still, but this, and the info on Classes shared by @RonRosenfeld give me great way to tinker and learn more about how they work.